# How to get the values from a specific json item value from a list of json records from a TRESTResponse in Delphi

Tags: delphi-11-alexandria

I have JSON similar to below. I need to get the list of "tenantName" values and add these to a ComboBox. How do I do this in Delphi?

```
[
    {
        "id": "e1eede29-f875-4a5d-8470-17f6a29a88b1",
        "tenantId": "70784a63-d24b-46a9-a4db-0e70a274b056",
        "tenantType": "ORGANISATION",
        "tenantName": "Maple Florist",
    },
    {
        "id": "32587c85-a9b3-4306-ac30-b416e8f2c841",
        "tenantId": "e0da6937-de07-4a14-adee-37abfac298ce",
        "tenantType": "ORGANISATION",
        "tenantName": "Adam Demo Company (NZ)",
    },
    {
        "id": "74305bf3-12e0-45e2-8dc8-e3ec73e3b1f9",
        "tenantId": "c3d5e782-2153-4cda-bdb4-cec791ceb90d",
        "tenantType": "PRACTICEMANAGER",
        "tenantName": "Geographe Steelworks",
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the `TRESTResponse.JSONValue` property to `TJSONArray`, then loop through its elements, casting each one to `TJSONObject` and extracting the desired value from them.